# How I can a page in a UWP Pivot check if it's the active page

Tags: uwp

I have a `Pivot` (tab) control with several `Page`s that are subscribed to background events (eg network IO, Serial IO, etc).

When certain background events are fired the `Page`s display `MessageDialog`s.

The problem is that because all `Page`s in a `Pivot` are active when the parent with the `Pivot` is, I can be on `Page1` and have `Page2` throw a `MessageDialog` in response to a background event that's only relevant/useful if I'm on `Page2`.

```
private void ReceivedSomeEvent(Object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    var t = Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
    {
        var dialog = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Some Event Complete");
        await dialog.ShowAsync();
    });
}
```

What I'd like to do is to wrap the `MessageDialog` logic in an `if (pageHasFocus)` check, but I don't of a property on the `Page` to check, or an event pair/method override pair that I can use to set a boolean flag appropriately.

Comment: Is the Pivot Item content a `Page`? Could you show more code about it?

Comment: There is an event > SelectionChanged that is triggered when selecting a tab in the Pivot. Can't you use that to 'set' an IsFocus property on the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
private async void MyPivot_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
     if (MyPivot.SelectedIndex == 0)
     {
          // page1 code here
     }
     else if (MyPivot.SelectedIndex == 1)
     {
          // page2 code here
     }
}
```